# How to calculate query that access system view cost in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, performance, performance-testing, query-performance

For a query that returns if there are any active transactions within current session ,

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM 
  v$transaction t
  INNER JOIN v$session s ON (t.ses_addr = s.saddr )      
  INNER JOIN v$mystat m  ON  (s.sid = m.sid )    
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

`EXPLAIN` shows 0 cost. However, that doesn't seem to be true. Periodically running this query in high load environment causes server to waste almost all its resources on it.

What is the right way to estimate impact of such queries (I believe the same problem occurs not for just this particular query, but anything that involves system views)?

Thanks.

Comment: You can autotrace the statement, but that gives information after the execution, not before.  This particular statement will perform better by replacing `INNER JOIN v$mystat m  ON  (s.sid = m.sid )` with `AND s.sid = sys_context('USERENV','SID')`, although I'm not sure what the this query could accomplish.  Seems like it could just as well be `SELECT 0 from dual;`.

Comment: @LeighRiffel this will tell if the current transaction has [uncommited changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299694/oracle-how-to-find-out-if-there-is-a-transaction-pending). There are [more efficient ways to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506456/how-can-i-tell-if-i-have-uncommitted-work-in-an-oracle-transaction) however.

Comment: @Vincent Malgrat Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I agree, it's not very efficient way, but how to measure efficiency in such cases except static code analysys ?

Comment: @a1ex07: the explain plan cost is a rough approximation so it shouldn't be your main way to evaluate the efficiency of a query. The true cost of a query can be revealed with a trace. Trace your actual query and all alternative queries and the tkprof will reveal which one is the most efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some (all?) dynamic `V$` views are based not on dictionary tables but on memory structures, so the traditinoal stats are not collected and therefore the optimizer can't compute the cost of queries on those views.

However,  the explain plan cost is only a rough approximation of the expected work so it shouldn't be your only way to evaluate the efficiency of a query. The true cost of a query can be revealed with a trace. Trace your actual query and all alternative queries and the tkprof will reveal which one is the most efficient.

For your query in particular, it seems you want to determine if your current session has uncommited work. Alternate queries are described in the following SO questions :

- [How can I tell if I have uncommitted work in an Oracle transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/506456/119634)
- [How to find out if there is a transaction pending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299694/oracle-how-to-find-out-if-there-is-a-transaction-pending)

Can you try the queries in these questions and tell us which one is the most efficient (on your high load environment)?

Comment: Thanks. Also, after doing some research , I believe the cheapest way to check if there is a transaction within current session, is to start a new transaction (which throws an error if there is a pending transaction) and rollback it. It also doesn't require any extra privileges

Comment: How do you start a new transaction?

Comment: ok, Oracle doesn't let `start/begin transaction`. However, I can do, for instance, `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED` that fails if I have any pending transactions.

Comment: Thanks, it definitely looks like the most efficient way.